# Javascript ReactJs Importing multiple components as groups possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a reactjs project and creating many components which I then import into other components.

At the moment if I wanted to import 5 components I need to do this:

```
import C1 from './components/Component1';
import C2 from './components/Component2';
import C3 from './components/Component3';
import C4 from './components/Component4';
import C5 from './components/Component5';
```

So, if I had 50 components and needed to use them all it would take 50 lines of import.

Is there anyway to create component groups and import them or a better way to import lots of components into a page?

Answer (score 5):

You could create a file that simply re-exports all components like this:

```
// components/index.js
import C1 from './components/Component1';
import C2 from './components/Component2';
import C3 from './components/Component3';
import C4 from './components/Component4';
import C5 from './components/Component5';

export {
  C1,
  C2,
  C3,
  C4,
  C5
};
```

And in your app code:

```
import * as Components from './components';
Components.C1
```

To add components you just need to change the `index.js`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly only exporting:

```
export {default as AcceptanceOptions} from './AcceptanceEnum';
export * from './AcceptanceEnum';
```

With the first one exports the default, with the second one you export all the rest.

To import them in your component:

```
import { AcceptanceEnum, AcceptanceOptions} from "../../Enums/index";
import * as enums from "../../Enums/index"
```

With the first one you only import Acceptances, with the second one you import al the exports included in the index.js/ts file